# Do I need to have Windows installed to run Wine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, wine

Do I need to have Windows installed on my machine for make Wine run?  Or I don't need Windows installed, Wine has it owns libraries?

Answer (score 7):

Wine supplies native versions of a number of base and important libraries. Windows is not required in order to use them.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is No.

WINE attempts to provide the window's api with real bindings to the underlying Linux based APIS.

Answer (score 2):

No, wine is a self standing set of adapted windows libraries, but, if you do have windows installed and some programs installed under windows, you can sometimes run those in linux by using wine to launch the executables.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not! Don't need Windows installed.

WINE means 'Wine Is Not an Emulator' so in facts only libraries you need to run windows applications are installed on your system.. And this is not an entire Windows running on your system.

[Wine's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) is really instructive, you can read it! And I've post a question about Wine few months ago. [Read It too!](https://superuser.com/questions/14594/why-is-wine-not-an-emulator)